# What is the difference between escaping a keycode in an <expr> noremap?

Tags: vim

I am writing a script to cycle through the pop up menu using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and I see that people often [escape the key notations](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE):

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"
```

I am currently using the following without the `\` slashes and it produces the exact same behavior:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "<C-y>" : "<C-g>u<CR>"
```

When do I need to add the backslash escape to ensure it is most compatible, or does this backslash have no meaning within this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the `\` is escaping the entire expression inside the `<>`, turning it into a regular string. From the [vimhelp website](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#%3C%3E):

> Examples are often given in the `<>` notation.  Sometimes this is just to make
>   clear what you need to type, but often it can be typed literally, e.g., with
>   the `:map` command.  The rules are:
>
> 1. Any printable characters are typed directly, except backslash and `<`
> 2. A backslash is represented with `"\\"`, double backslash, or `"<Bslash>"`.
> 3. **A real `<` is represented with `"\<"` or `"<lt>"`. When there is no
>       confusion possible, a `<` can be used directly.**

It goes on to give an example for mapping <kbd>C-H</kbd> to the six characters "< Home>". I've replaced it with "< yes>" because home is a keyword.

```
:imap <C-H> \<yes>
```

Try it yourself; <kbd>C-H</kbd> will print the literal string "< yes>".

So for your command, it's escaping the <kbd>C-y</kbd> and <kbd>C-g</kbd> key sequences into their literal string representations; `"<C-y>"` and `"<C-g>"`, respectively. Originally, this was done because the `<expr>` attribute makes it so the command expects to get the *string representation* of the command to execute, not the already-parsed control sequence itself. But this escaping is useless, as it's already in double quotes. That's why the behavior doesn't change when you remove the slashes.

Comment: That's not what happens for me in either case - if I do `:imap <C-H> \<yes>` then in insert mode do a <C-H> it outputs literally `\<yes>` with the backslash. If I do `:imap <expr> <C-H> \<yes>` and try it says `Invalid expression: \<yes>`. I am on Vim 8 if that makes a difference.

Comment: @RillyR yes, my example is covering your first case. I will edit my answer to include the use of your `<expr>` attribute.

Comment: Ok, I found it. `cpoptions` includes the backslash flag by default which makes the `\\` a literal character rather than an escape character. Removing it shows the differences. Thanks!

Comment: @RillyR Glad to help. For the `cpoptions` flag you mention (`B`), you can make sure your commands are compatible by escaping with `<lt>` rather than `\\`.